# cakePHP save to multiple models

Tags: cakephp, model, save

I have 2 models I need to save to. In this instance, I do not need cakePHP to saveAll(), but want to save the content manually.

In my view I have the formHelper setup as "Model2.fieldname" and on post, if I do a pr(), there is an associative array created with [Model2] with the fields.

my code in the controller:

```
 if($this->request->is("post") {
      if($this->Model1->save($this->request->data) {
           if($this->Model1->Model2->save($this->request->data) {
                $this->Session->setFlash("Success");
           }
      }
 }
```

It goes ahead and stores the data for model1, but fails on model2. It creates an empty record in the table because there is a created and modified table field, but the rest of the fields are blank. It also fails the validation for model2 (so it does not do any validation.)

Model1 hasOne Model2

I havent done this before so I am convinced I am doing something wrong, so if anyone can help thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cakephp's `saveAssociated()` method:

```
$this->Model1->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
```

Read about [**saveAssociated()**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)